# Keeping tags clean from the start

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to provide some basic reminders regarding tags. As many of you will know from the other SE sites you participate in, tags are not on the top of the pile functionality wise in the SE sites. However if we keep it a sensible taxonomy from the start we have a good chance to make it better.

Let me start out with the obvious.

- **Look for existing tags.** Even now in beta. No, especially now in beta. Open the tags page and have a look at it before creating new ones.
- Think before you tag. [Don't create meta tags.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)
- Be on the look out for bad tags. We already have some the roomba will delete tonight. (Someone created [fiction](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) ...) Edit out those abominations early and with prejudice.
- If you are unsure about it, ask about it on meta.

Let's do it right from the start.

Comment: Meta tags should have their own Meta post (pun intended).